# jQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**EDIT** I FIGURED IT OUT. I just needed to add the jquery and in Joomla you do this by going to your template/index.php and adding this line by "//Add Javascript Frameworks" `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`.

**WORKING**

I need some help converting this code to javascript.

Currently it's not working in my browser using jQuery. I load the AJAX library and everything but it's not working. I just added a dropdown and div's with the same ID's as the ones I'm using to make it easier.

If I preview the form which I created in the software I'm using it is working as intended with this jQuery code; however once I save the changes to the form and go to the live site it's not doing anything. (The software is RSForm Pro for Joomla.. Yes, I'm still new to this)

Any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#DeliveryPlaces').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == '1') {
      $("#LocationDelivery1").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery2").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery3").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery4").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery5").hide();
    } else if (this.value == '2') {
      $("#LocationDelivery1").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery2").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery3").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery4").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery5").hide();
    } else if (this.value == '3') {
      $("#LocationDelivery1").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery2").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery3").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery4").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery5").hide();
    } else if (this.value == '4') {
      $("#LocationDelivery1").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery2").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery3").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery4").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery5").hide();
    } else if (this.value == '5') {
      $("#LocationDelivery1").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery2").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery3").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery4").show();
      $("#LocationDelivery5").show();
    } else {
      $("#LocationDelivery1").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery2").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery3").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery4").hide();
      $("#LocationDelivery5").hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="DeliveryPlaces">
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div id="LocationDelivery1">LocationDelivery1</div>
<div id="LocationDelivery2">LocationDelivery2</div>
<div id="LocationDelivery3">LocationDelivery3</div>
<div id="LocationDelivery4">LocationDelivery4</div>
<div id="LocationDelivery5">LocationDelivery5</div>
```

Comment: This is already javascript. :) Bad jokes aside, did you try something™?

Comment: 'this' is javascript but you begin with jquery 'this' is equals $(this) in jquey

Comment: @sinisake Its not javascript

Comment: Hahah then I'm worse at this than I thought. Yeah I tried hiding the div's on form load, a different AJAX library source.

Comment: Let me try using with the $ sign for "this"

Comment: Just read the source code of jquery functions how they are implemented. And voila! you have pure JavaScript :)

Comment: Are you running this from localhost on Chrome? Try using Firefox or start a web server (like WAMP, XAMPP, LAMP or any of your choice). Chrome blocks localhost javascript so the problem might be as stupid as this. If not, let me know :)

Comment: Make sure that the code you are trying to run is implemented AFTER the jquery library (which you refer as ajax library)

Comment: Well the site is hosted on godaddy and I used joomla for to design most of it. I also assumed it's something with Chrome. I'll have a look and let you know.

Comment: @noa-dev it is running after it. Thank you. I think it's possibly Chrome blocking it.

Comment: @mnemosdev you were right! The jquery wasn't loading due to joomla not enabling it by default; you have to add the framework address/url to your index.php. It has a specific location for it! So thanks I went with your suggestion.

Comment: @MailBlade Im gonna add an answer so we can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chosen in the comments by the OP:

Are you running this from localhost on Chrome? Try using Firefox or start a web server (like WAMP, XAMPP, LAMP or any of your choice). Chrome blocks localhost javascript so the problem might be as stupid as this. If not, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some solution for you, but if you don't wish to use it this way, you can extract parts of code, i've done it right for 5 options, and 5 divs, and the script will loop on the value you selected and show them, all others will loop and hide.

```js
document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").onchange = function() {
  var value = parseInt(this.value == '-' ? 0 : this.value);
  // show
  if (value>0) {
      for (var i=1; i<=value; i++) {
           document.getElementById("LocationDelivery"+i).style.display = 'block';
           }
     }
  // hide
  if (value<=4) {
      for (var i=value+1; i<=5; i++) {
           document.getElementById("LocationDelivery"+i).style.display = 'none';
          }
     }
};
```

```html
<select id="DeliveryPlaces">
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div id="LocationDelivery1">LocationDelivery1</div>
<div id="LocationDelivery2">LocationDelivery2</div>
<div id="LocationDelivery3">LocationDelivery3</div>
<div id="LocationDelivery4">LocationDelivery4</div>
<div id="LocationDelivery5">LocationDelivery5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post man. I was actually looking into a loop but could not get it right since I have limited knowledge of it. I will test it and let you know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to load the library before your script, just above the closing body tag. Also, you might try using $(this).val() instead of this.value. I've done a quick jQuery script in case it works correctly on your browser, and using switch statement rather tan if statement.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/noLz7wr3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#DeliveryPlaces').on('change', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    $('.delivery').hide();
    switch($(this).val()){
     case "1":
       $('#LocationDelivery1').show();
      break;
     case "2":
       $('#LocationDelivery2').show();
      break;
     case "3":
       $('#LocationDelivery3').show();
      break;
     case "4":
       $('#LocationDelivery4').show();
      break;
     case "5":
       $('#LocationDelivery5').show();
      break;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.delivery {
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="DeliveryPlaces">
    <option value selected disabled>Select Location Delivery</option>
    <option value="1">Location Delivery 1</option>
    <option value="2">Location Delivery 2</option>
    <option value="3">Location Delivery 3</option>
    <option value="4">Location Delivery 4</option>
    <option value="5">Location Delivery 5</option>
    
  </select>
</form>

    <div class="delivery" id="LocationDelivery1">Location Delivery 1</div>
    <div class="delivery" id="LocationDelivery2">Location Delivery 2</div>
    <div class="delivery" id="LocationDelivery3">Location Delivery 3</div>
    <div class="delivery" id="LocationDelivery4">Location Delivery 4</div>
    <div class="delivery" id="LocationDelivery5">Location Delivery 5</div>
```

Comment: This is great! However if you choose "5" in the dropdown, it must show all locations..

Comment: If you can see, "delivery" class is set to all Location Delivery divs. You can control all of them just by selecting that class in jQuery. So, in case 5: $('.delivery').show();

Comment: Ahhh thanks a lot ! Didn't even see that! It's better to use classes I see now.

Comment: Can I ask another question? What is the purpose of the single "e" after function in the "on.('change')" line?

Comment: Using e (event toggled by select change) as a parameter, preventDefault() function allows to stop any default actions such as submitting the form. In this case is not that necessary, but I added it anyway.